# How to change Table name and column name of jobs table in laravel queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I want to change table name and column name of jobs table which is genetared  by creating a  laravel queue in laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `queue.php` file in the `config` folder where you can find

```
'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
],
```

for the column name, i think there is no option if not to use the ones defined in the usual migration

Note: this might change based on the version of laravel you are using, but in every version there is this config file where you can configure the table to use

Comment: but any way to change the column names  ? I dont want some cloumns there and need to rename of columns name as per need. @Berto99

Comment: @AakashSitole why in the world you want to rename them? and btw, the columns are not optionals, they serve a specific porpuse, so you must not take them out

Comment: can I send all mails through one common job in laravel ? @ Berto99